# Can't Understand this js code( can't understand text +=arr[i]+"<br>")?

Tags: javascript

Can't Understand  `var text="";` and `text +=arr[i]+"<br>"`

```
<script>
var str = "Hello";
var arr = str.split("");
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
text += arr[i] + "<br>"
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "str" variable defined as string = "hello".
2. `var arr = str.split("");`
   it used to split str string to be array of chars `h,e,l,l,o`
3. `text="";` text variable is an empty variable defined as string.
4. variable `i` defined as anumber from 0 to 4 (arr.length || str.length)
5. `text +=arr[i] +'<br/>';` add "arr" array peices to text [empty] string

see this is the same without for loops

```
    var str = "Hello";
    var arr = str.split("");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    arr[0]+"<br/>"+ // h + breakline
    arr[1]+"<br/>"+ // e + breakline
    arr[2]+"<br/>"+ // l + breakline
    arr[3]+"<br/>"+ // l + breakline
    arr[4]+"<br/>"; // o + breakline
```

Comment: if text += arr[i]+'<br/ >' then output should be h,he,hell,hello

Answer (score -1):

full writing of

```
text += arr[i] + "<br>";
```

is

```
text = text + arr[i] + "<br>";
```

this code is adding new html line after each character.

Comment: so why not h then he then hel then hell then hello

Comment: this doesn't give output you typed. what exactly do you want to do ?   It will give h<br>e<br>l<br>l<br>o<br>.               You should try jsFiddle or plunker for this.

Comment: actually i can't understand because if text = text +arr[i] +" <br>" then value of text is change in every loop w hen i = 0, then text = h, then when i =1 then why not text = H+[i]+<"br">= HE .why it is only E.i can't understand this part